# Modifications of DFS algorithm to check vertices in a graph

Tags: algorithm, depth-first-search, vertices

Just need a pseudo code, not the entire run code.
Give the modifications needed to either the DFS algorithm so that it can check if the vertices in a graph can be labeled with 0's and 1's such that there is not an edge between vertices with the same label.

Comment: 1. Add whatever approach you might have come up with. 2. Sounds like graph coloring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph that you are looking for is called a Bipartite graph. A modification to DFS would be like this (let color[node] be -1 in the beginning for all nodes):

- let color[1] = 1.
- start DFS from node 1
- inside your DFS color all uncolored neighbors of the current node with a color opposite to the color of the current node.
- if there exists a colored neighbor with color equal to current node's color then there is no solution.

Comment: I'm assuming the graph is connected, if not then you should do the same for every uncolored node until all nodes are colored.